# UIScrollView bounds.size

Tags: xcode, uiscrollview, bounds

I am using a UIScrollView in an iPhone xib, and a property called myScrollView to read the size of the scroll view.

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *myScrollView;

When I try to read or use the bounds.size of the scroll view it comes out different than the dimentions I have set up in the xib scaled to 320 x 117. But myScrollView.bounds.size.height returns 583. Shouldn't it read the same? Should I set the size some other way?

log statement:

```
NSLog(@"scrollview x y: %f,%f", myScrollView.bounds.size.width, myScrollView.bounds.size.height);
```

output:

```
2012-06-28 11:38:13.150 MyApp[1380:707] scrollview x y: 320.000000,583.000000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bounds of an UIView is the rectangle, expressed as a location (x,y) and size (width,height) relative to its own coordinate system (0,0).

The frame of an UIView is the rectangle, expressed as a location (x,y) and size (width,height) relative to the superview it is contained within.

You are setting the frame not the bounds in interface builder.

Comment: Thanks! but the frame property returns the same value:   NSLog(@"scrollview x y: %f,%f", myScrollView.frame.size.width, myScrollView.frame.size.height); 2012-06-28 12:02:39.290 MyApp[1467:707] scrollview x y: 320.000000,583.000000

Comment: I think instead of changing the contentsize you change the frame of the scroll view

Comment: I did code it eventually, and also had something to do with the method I was calling it in apparently. While in viewDidLoad, works fine.